# Visual Studio 2010: Add new class file that inherits from existing class?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, inheritance, resharper, contextmenu

Is there a way in Visual Studio 2010 to add a new file (class) to a project that inherits from an existing base class, abstract or otherwise?  This seems like a simple concept but I can't find a way to do it.

I'd like to be able to for example right click a class name in the IDE and and select "add new inheriting class" or something similar. Just one of those things that would save a lot of repetition. Ideally it would implement (generate stubs) for abstract members, etc.

Does anyone know a way to do this either through stock VS2010 or ReSharper? I've dug through both and can't find anything. Interestingly enough, Resharper will allow for generating a superclass, but not a subclass..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think it's actually faster to right click -> add base class then to add a class file and type : Base behind it.

If you want to implement an abstract class you can right click on the base class and select "Implement Abstract Members"

You can also use the Class Diagram tool (right click a project and select View Class Diagram) then add a class and drag an inheritance arrow from the toolbox onto it.

Comment: Thanks - I agree if it's a non abstract class it might be faster just to add the `: Base` manually. I just find all of the steps to add, inherit, and implement could be faster as a context item. Thanks for the class diagram tool - hadn't though of this. Not exactly what I was looking for but probably the closest answer I can get.

Answer (score 2):

If you are adding Form or User control, this option is available in VS2010, under Windows Forms Tab.
[image: New Windows Form - In Visual Studio 2010 Express]

Comment: Thanks - I should have specified I'm talking only about adding a basic class file, not a form, etc. The option isn't there when just adding a class.

Answer (score 2):

You could [create a new item template](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s365byhx.aspx) for the base class(es) you find yourself using most often. Or you could [extend Visual Studio](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vstudio/ff718165) and roll your own.